# Localized eigenfunctions of drift Laplacians

Tags: reference-request, sp.spectral-theory, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

I am looking for literature which discusses localization of eigenfunctions of drift Laplacians, i.e. $L\underline u=-\Delta \underline u+\underline{v}.\nabla \underline u$ in 2D/3D domains with Dirichlet/Neumann boundary conditions.
Most literature that I was able to locate deals with Schrodinger type operators instead.